# How to resize images for wallpaper?

Tags: command-line, 12.04, desktop-background, image-processing

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying to set a rotating picture of Earth as my wallpaper. I'm currently using "Scheduled Tasks" with this command:

```sh
wget -O static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg \
     --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10" \
     http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg
```

How can I resize the image in the same command to 1280x1024?

Also: `>/dev/null 2>&1` gets added every time the command is run. Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That may be the incorrect syntax for the `wget` command for your desired result: simply running `wget http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg` will save the image as `1600.jpg` in the current directory. Also, it looks like the `--user-agent` option is not necessary for that website.

Resizing the image will distort it a little bit, because you're trying to essentially "compress" an amount of data into a larger data container - meaning data will have to be added based on assumptions made by the image editor. You can try it anyway, though, using ImageMagick. It is provided by the `imagemagick` package.

There are one of two methods you can use to convert it. The first one, which is probably more preferable because it will not distort the image as much, is to keep the image's aspect ratio and resize it to 1280 x 887, which may still work for a 1280 x 1024 desktop background if you have, for example, a green solid background color set behind it or something. To resize the image this way, use:

```
convert 1600.jpg -resize 1280 x 887 1600_2.jpeg
```

or

```
convert 1600.jpg -resize 1280 x 1024 1600_2.jpeg
```

This will shrink the image horizontally, but leave its vertical dimension the same.

The second method will involve shrinking the image horizontally and stretching it vertically. This will distort the image more, and the syntax for the command is:

```
convert 1600.jpeg -resize 1280 x 1024\> 1600_2.jpeg
```

(Source: [ImageMagick website](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize))

Comment: At first, I only had the 'wget http://static.die.net/earth/mercator/1600.jpg ' but it gave me this error "(Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x47 0x49)". Knowing it gave me this error, how do I fix the command?

Thanks for the help!